# How do i connect 2 input boxes to a single function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
> weightCalc(event) { console.log(event) }
> 
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <div>
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> <label>
>         Stones 
> 
>         <input type="textbox" name="test" onChange={this.weightCalc}/>
>         </label>
>         
>         <label>
>           Pounds <input type="textbox" name="test2" onChange={this.weightCalc} />  
>         </label>
```

i want to be able to use one function with the values from the 2 inputs and then update the state please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will you to update based on the name of the input fields, but they should be matching key values in the state to update/sync them with the specific values.

```
 weightCalc(event) { this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }); }
 
   render() {
     return (
       <div> 
       <label>
         Stones 
           <input type="textbox" name="test" onChange={this.weightCalc} value={this.state.test}/>
         </label>
         
         <label>
           Pounds <input type="textbox" name="test2" onChange={this.weightCalc} value={this.state.test2} />  
         </label>
```

Comment: Is there a way for the function to receive the values instead of updating state just yet?

Comment: @code_novice_1234 Yes, you could do the following in the `onChange` attribute -> `onChange=(ev) => this.weightCalc(ev.target.value)` - This will pass the value directly to the function, however, you won't be able to dynamically determine the name of the input to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

I used two refs and update each other in `onChange`. Something like:

```js
const AmazingInput = () => {
  const ref1 = useRef(null);
  const ref2 = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <Input ref={ref1} onChange={(e) => ref2.current.target.value = e.target.value}>
      <Input ref={ref2} onChange={(e) => ref1.current.target.value = e.target.value}>
    </div>
  )
}
```